# Service закрывается после запуска onstartCommand Intent (has extras)

Tags: java, android, android-service

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Почему после получения Intent в onstartCommnas Service вызывает onDestroy?

Ведь я получил данные из Intent. Но по какой - то причине я получаю ошибку

`Intent (has extras)`

Comment: а где ошибка то?

Comment: @SviatVolkov, Я же говорю ошибки нет никакой. Просто после onStartCommnad вызывается onDestroy. Это же сервис он должен висеть в процессе. Я не вызывал stopService чтобы он закрылся. А он берет и закрывается сам

Comment: так чтобы сервис висел в фоне, он должен быть foreground. обычный сервис отработал и умер.

Comment: @SviatVolkov, Может все таки backgrond))

Comment: Дело даже не не в back/foreground, а в том что ему просто нечего делать, а раз делать нечего, то и висеть в фоне незачем.

Comment: Какой класс наследует ваш `ServiceOfflineLoader`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не правильно Intent передавал поэтому и ошибка была